# Cannot add custom attribute data to quote_item when customer is logged in?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I have custom field "**some_field**" in 4 Magento tables: **quote_item, quote, order_item, order**.

When a customer is not logged in data is saved in the quote_item and up to order_item after order is completed without any problem.

But when customer is logged in (Magento user/Facebook log in) "**some_field**" is not inserted(no new record with null value).

I have overriden CartController.php and added custom addAction in order to make some pre validations to "**some_field**", which works fine for not logged in customers.

In config.xml i have:

```
<fieldsets>
<sales_convert_quote_item>
<some_field>
            <to_order_item>*</to_order_item>
</some_field>
</sales_convert_quote_item>

<sales_convert_quote>
<some_field>
            <to_order>*</to_order>
</some_field>               
</sales_convert_quote>
</fieldsets>
```

What i am missing?

What differs from guests and logged in customers when you add a product to Magento shopping cart?

Comment: Are you using flat tables? If so, you'll need to add your field to the `sales_flat_quote_item` etc. tables as well.

Comment: Yes, the tables that i have added "some_filed" are sales_flat_quote_item, sales_flat_quote, sales_flat_order_item, sales_flat_order.